# Tensorflow 2.0: minimize a simple function

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```py
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np

    x = tf.Variable(2, name='x', trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        t.watch(x)
        log_x = tf.math.log(x)
        y = tf.math.square(log_x)

    opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(0.5)
    # train = opt.minimize(lambda: y, var_list=[x]) # FAILS

    @tf.function
    def f(x):
        log_x = tf.math.log(x)
        y = tf.math.square(log_x)
        return y

    yy = f(x)
    train = opt.minimize(lambda: yy, var_list=[x]) # ALSO FAILS
```

Yields ValueError:

```
No gradients provided for any variable: ['x:0'].
```

This looks like the examples they partially give. I'm not sure if this is a bug with eager or 2.0 or something I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**

Pasted an embellished version of the solution below as there were some issues and interesting notes.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf

    x = tf.Variable(3, name='x', trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as t:
        # log_x = tf.math.log(x)
        # y = tf.math.square(log_x)
        y = (x - 1) ** 2

    opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

    def get_gradient_wrong(x0):
        # this does not work, it does not actually update the value of x
        x.assign(x0)
        return t.gradient(y, [x])

    def get_gradient(x0):
        # this works
        x.assign(x0)
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as t:
            y = (x - 1) ** 2
        return t.gradient(y, [x])

    #### Option 1
    def a(x0, tol=1e-8, max_iter=10000):
        # does not appear to work properly
        x.assign(x0)
        err = np.Inf # step error (banach), not actual erro
        i = 0
        while err > tol:
            x0 = x.numpy()
            # IMPORTANT: WITHOUT THIS INSIDE THE LOOP THE GRADIENTS DO NOT UPDATE
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as t:
                y = (x - 1) ** 2
            gradients = t.gradient(y, [x])
            l = opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [x]))
            err = np.abs(x.numpy() - x0)
            print(err, x.numpy(), gradients[0].numpy())
            i += 1
            if i > max_iter:
                print(f'stopping at max_iter={max_iter}')
                return x.numpy()
        print(f'stopping at err={err}<{tol}')
        return x.numpy()

    #### Option 2
    def b(x0, tol=1e-8, max_iter=10000):
        x.assign(x0)
        # To use minimize you have to define your loss computation as a funcction
        def compute_loss():
            log_x = tf.math.log(x)
            y = tf.math.square(log_x)
            return y
        err = np.Inf # step error (banach), not actual erro
        i = 0
        while err > tol:
            x0 = x.numpy()
            train = opt.minimize(compute_loss, var_list=[x])
            err = np.abs(x.numpy() - x0)
            print(err, x.numpy())
            i += 1
            if i > max_iter:
                print(f'stopping at max_iter={max_iter}')
                return x.numpy()
        print(f'stopping at err={err}<{tol}')
        return x.numpy()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're doing something wrong. You have two options:

### Use the tape to compute the gradients

In that case, you have to use the optimizer only to apply the update rule.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(2, name='x', trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    # no need to watch a variable:
    # trainable variables are always watched
    log_x = tf.math.log(x)
    y = tf.math.square(log_x)

#### Option 1

# Is the tape that computes the gradients!
trainable_variables = [x]
gradients = t.gradient(y, trainable_variables)
# The optimize applies the update, using the variables
# and the optimizer update rule
opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_variables))
```

### Define the loss as a function

In this case, you can use the optimizer `.minimize` method, that will create the tape to compute the gradient + update the parameters for you

```py
#### Option 2
# To use minimize you have to define your loss computation as a funcction
def compute_loss():
    log_x = tf.math.log(x)
    y = tf.math.square(log_x)
    return y
train = opt.minimize(compute_loss, var_list=trainable_variables)
```

Comment: And the important, subtle, point in the loss funcion appears to be that you need to CONSTRUCT the loss in the function. For example, you can not just construct y and pass in the loss as lambda: y. I don't fully understand why not yet.

Comment: Because that function is wrapped in a gradien tape, and the tape records the operations. If you pass `y`, the tape has no clue about the operations that created `y` and thus no gradient can be computed

Comment: And for the first example, it appears one needs to reconstruct the gradient tape again and again inside a loop. Same pattern as with the function basically. Is this actually the correct way to do this? Feels like we are still missing something.

Comment: You're not missing anything, a training loop is just the computation of the loss inside the tape, followed by application of the update rule through the optimizer. This gives you a lot of flexibility since you can do customizations like "every odd iteration I clip the gradient" or anying else you want. Using a tape to compute the gradients is fast, don't worry about the performance

Comment: Interesting. So basically this is the most general "dynamic graph" pattern by default. An hence the graph is expected to be reconstructed each time. Awesome if this is fast even for large networks.

Comment: Yes, you only need a graph when you have to keep track of the operation you are execution, otherwise is useless. Therefore, the tape is used to keep track of the operations and build the graph for you. This is fast, but if you want it faster you can annotate the function that computes the forward + applies the gradient with `@tf.function`

Comment: How does one store and track intermediate variables that are only definable inside the loss function? For example what if I want log_x to persist?

Comment: Use the custom training loop version, and use a helper variable defined outside the loop to assign the value you want to store

Comment: Ok, how? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Perhaps it is better to create a new question with a small example of what you want to achieve (I don't have any reference, I just described how I would do it)

Comment: Ok, here is a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921207/basic-function-minimisation-and-variable-tracking-in-tensorflow-2-0

Answer (score 4):

I've up-voted the accepted solution above as well, but I still needed some time to get an end to end solution running, so let me share that with you as well, the code is solving some simple mathematical puzzle:

> f(x)=x-(6/7)*x-1/7
> g(x)=f(f(f(f(x))))
> Find x such that g(x) == 0

```py
!pip install setuptools --upgrade
!pip install -q tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.__version__ #=> '2.0.0-beta1'

   


@tf.function
def f(x):
    return x-(6/7)*x-1/7

print(tf.autograph.to_code(step.python_function))

x = tf.Variable(0, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float64)
y = tf.constant([0], dtype=tf.float64)

@tf.function
def g(x):
    return f(f(f(f(x))))

print(tf.autograph.to_code(compute.python_function))

# Create a list of variables which needs to be adjusted during the training process, in this simple case it is only x
variables = [x]
    
# Instantiate a Gradient Decent Optimizer variant, it this case learning rate and specific type of optimizer doesn't matter too much
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(0.5)
    
# We need to somehow specify the error between the actual value of the evaluated function in contrast to the target (which is zero)
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
    
# Since we are not running inside a TensorFlow execution graph anymore we need some means of keeping state of the gradient during training
# so a persistent GradientTape is your friend and the way to go in TensorFlow 2.0
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        
    #Let's train for some iterations
    for i in range(1000):
            
        # given the actual value of X (which we now continueously adjust in order to find the root of the equation)
        y_pred = g(x)
            
        # At this point we are actually setting the whole equation to zero. Since X is variable, the goal is to find an X which satisfies the condition
        # (that the whole equations becomes zero). We are doing this by defining a loss which becomes zero if y_pred approximates y. Or in other words,
        # since y is zero, the loss becomes zero if y_pred approximates zero.
        loss = loss_object(y,y_pred)
            
        # Now the magic happens. Loss basically represents the error surface and is only dependent on X. So now let's compute the first derivative and
        # see in which direction we need to adjust X in order to minimize the error and getting a value (output of the nested equations) closer to zero
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, variables)
            
        # Once we've found this magic number magically, let's update the value of X based on this magic number in order to perform better on the next
        # iteration
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, variables))
           
        # And now it's pretty cool, we can just print the current error (loss) and the actual value of X in each iteration. At the end of the training,
        # we've found the optima wich a loss / error close to zero and a value of X close to 400 where 400 is the correct solution.
        # Small deviations from the true solutions stem from numeric errors
        print('Loss: {}, X: {}'.format(loss.numpy(), x.numpy()))
```