# How do you apply a loss using an optimizer on a image

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to achieve neural art transfer. So my question is now I have a loss how do I apply it to an image. Below I have created an optimiser a loss function and a randomly generated image. How do I apply a custom optimiser to this? Whenever I run this is getting `'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable` and I am kind of confused by this message. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
optimiser=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.05)
#All [content_image,style_image,generated_image] the same Shape 1, H ,W ,C uint8

epochs=20
# pass content image through model
content_image_value=model(content_image.reshape(size_of_images))[-1] 
# pass styles image through model
style_image_values=model(style_image.reshape(size_of_images))[:-1]
# Randomly Generated Image
generated_image=tf.Variable(generated_image)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    # pass model generated image
    generate_image_values=model(generated_image)
    # Get the output we compare with the content
    content_generator_value=generate_image_values[-1]
    # Get the output we compare with the style
    style_generator_value=generate_image_values[:-1]
    loss=some_custom_loss() # returns a float64
    
    print(loss)
    # Minimise the error
    optimiser.minimize(loss,var_list=[generated_image])

    imshow(generated_image[0])
```

Comment: You can follow this post for a sample example on `minimize` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552715/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `minimize` function. This function is meant to operate inside a tensorflow `session`.

You need to modify your code as follows to minimize loss in eager mode:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    generate_image_values = model(generated_image)
    # Get the output we compare with the content
    content_generator_value = generate_image_values[-1]
    # Get the output we compare with the style
    style_generator_value = generate_image_values[:-1]
    loss = some_custom_loss() # returns a float64
print(loss)
# Get the gradients
grads = tape.gradient(loss, generated_image)
# minimize
opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, generated_image)
imshow(generated_image[0])
```